# How to make code shorter?

Tags: scala

Does it possible to eleminate if(map.nonEmpty) code string, make everything in one string?

```
def findEqSorted(arr:List[Elem]) = {
  val map = arr.groupBy(_.suit).filter(_._2.size >= 5)
  if(map.nonEmpty)
    Some(map.head._2.sortWith(_.num > _.num).take(5))
  else None
}
```

If I do it such way:

```
Option(arr.groupBy(_.suit).filter(_._2.size >= 5).head._2.sortWith(_.num > _.num).take(5))
```

Everything is ok if `filter(_._2.size >= 5)` returns nonEmpty Map, otherwise I get error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `map.head._2` to `map.headOption.map(_._2)`? This should at least avoid the if-else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing `filter` and then optionally doing `head`, you can condense this with `find`, which returns an Option for you:

```
def findEqSorted(arr: List[Elem]) = {
  arr.groupBy(_.suit).find(_._2.size >= 5).map {
    _._2.sortWith(_.num > _.num).take(5)
  }
}
```